# UnderscoreJS: groupby + sortby

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Any suggestion on how to do grupby + sortby together using UnderscoreJS?

Having following collection, I would like to find smallest price per season:

```
var d = [{ 
    "price": 27.25,
    "season": 2
},
{ 
    "price": 10,
    "season": 3
},
{ 
    "price": 21,
    "season": 2
}];
```

I was able to group using the below:

```
_.chain(d).groupBy('season').map(function(value, key) {
return {
            season: key,
            obj: value

        }
    }).value();
```

which gets me:

```
[
 {"season":"2","obj":[{"price":27.25,"season":2},{"price":21,"season":2}]},
 {"season":"3","obj":[{"price":10,"season":3}]}
]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @thefourtheye - [{ "season": 2, "price": 21 }, { "season": 3, "price": 10}]

Comment: Why you omit {"price":27.25,"season":2} ?

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan - sorry, that was a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var output = _.chain(d).groupBy("season").map(function (group) {
    return _.chain(group).sortBy("price").first().value();
}).value();
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ns2MJ/

Answer (score 1):

Get the minimum price of each season in your `map` function:

```
_.chain(d).groupBy('season').map(function(value, key) {
  return {
    season: key,
    price: _.chain(value).pluck('price').min().value()
  }
}).sortBy('price').value();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`_min`](http://underscorejs.org/#min) combined with [`_.property`](http://underscorejs.org/#property) to extract the smallest price in a group:

```
var output = _.chain(d).groupBy('season').map(function (group) {
    return _.min(group, _.property('price'));
}).value();
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/Edf5g/